# If I delete a windows 8.1 user, will remain family safety active?

Tags: windows-8.1, user-accounts, parental-controls

I have an user which has family safety enabled by the second user. If I delete the second user, will family safety remain active on the first user?

I am using Windows 8.1.
Also, I'm not sure if the second user is local or a default user; when I try to change its password with administrator (user account is named 'net user'), it returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

Any default Windows account **should not in any circumstances be deleted manually.** Windows can create additional user accounts to ensure the security of your computer, or to add additional features.

The certain account that you want to remove is explained [here](http://forums.techguy.org/windows-vista/666552-user-account-created-automatically.html), one of the answers also states:

> When you install .Net it creates this account. You can just leave it
>   alone.

If you remove this account, most likely some of your programs **will no longer work, have restricted functionality, or will have many problems (or even crash).**

To answer your question, no, deleting the account will not remove or restrict the 'family safety' feature of Windows 8.1, although you shouldn't even touch the .NET account in the first place.

Comment: But any of the users are not created automatically. All are created within control panel.

Comment: @user327764 Doesn't matter, they're still user accounts you shouldn't touch.